# Edit a single key in hash

Tags: ruby

I have a ruby hash

```
 obj =
{
"context":{
"conversationIDs": [1, 2, 5], "sessionID":2}
}
```

I want to edit the conversationIds key with new values and take the uniq of that. What I have tried

```
 merged = (
             {
context:        obj[:context].merge({
"conversationIDs":  [*obj[:context]["conversationIDs"], 2,
              1, 1].uniq })
             }
)
     puts merged
```

Actual Output:

```
{:context=>{:conversationIDs=>[2, 1]}}
```

Expected Output:

```
{:context=>{:conversationIDs=>[2, 1, 5]}, :sessionID=>2 }
```

5 is missing in the output, how to sustain it?

Comment: `obj[:context]["conversationIDs"]` is not `obj[:context][:conversationIDs]`. You are doing uniq of `[*nil, 2, 2, 1]`, which is correctly `[2, 1]`.

Comment: Oops typo, I meant `[*nil, 2, 1, 1]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do:

```
obj = {:context=>{:conversationIDs=>[1, 2, 5], :sessionID=>2}}

obj[:context][:conversationIDs] = (obj[:context][:conversationIDs] + [2, 1, 1]).uniq
obj
#=> {:context=>{:conversationIDs=>[1, 2, 5], :sessionID=>2}}
```

Or:

```
obj = {:context=>{:conversationIDs=>[1, 2, 5], :sessionID=>2}}

obj[:context][:conversationIDs] += [1,2,5]
obj[:context][:conversationIDs].uniq!
obj
#=> {:context=>{:conversationIDs=>[1, 2, 5], :sessionID=>2}}
```

Or – as engineersmnky suggested:

```
obj = {:context=>{:conversationIDs=>[1, 2, 5], :sessionID=>2}}

obj[:context][:conversationIDs].concat([2, 1, 1]).uniq!
obj
#=> {:context=>{:conversationIDs=>[1, 2, 5], :sessionID=>2}}
```

Comment: I would write the second one as `obj[:context][:conversationIDs].concat([2,1,1]).uniq!` just because I don't like the look of the hanging call to `uniq!`